# Как выполнить действие для каждого восьмого?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
var string = '';
for (var i = 0;i<65;i++) {
  if (//тут для каждого 8го) {}
    string += '\n\t';
  }
  string += '# ';
}
```

При выполнении для каждого восьмого должен выполняться `string += '\n\t';`
Как это можно реализовать?

UPD:

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
    board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Так должно было выйти к меня, но не вышло)

Comment: Второй блок кода **не имеет** отношения к вопросу. О чем это вообще?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ну, я пытался добиться такого поведения. Добавил, что бы парень снизу глянул

Comment: ru.SO - не ваш персональный консультационный пункт. Второй блок кода не имеет отношения к тексту вопроса. Совсем.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проверяем остаток от деления счетчика на восемь, у каждого восьмого он будет одинаковый. Так как цикл от нуля, то он будет семь.

```
var string = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  if (i%8 === 7) { // оператор % - взятие остатка
    string += '\n\t';
  }
  string += '# ';
}
```

Кстати, предполагаю, что условие задумывалось как `i<64`, а не `i<65`

Comment: Возможно)Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Не заработало, дает всем этот код

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, что конкретно не заработало?) Хотите ровный квадрат - напишите i%8===0 (но это не совсем "для каждого восьмого")

Comment: Глянь код, который я добавил в вопрос, плиз. Как он работает, не до конца понимаю

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, никакого кода в вопрос не добавлено

Comment: готово, глянь плиз

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, не, так не пойдет. Это уже больше похоже "мне тут на другом форме код написали, объясните его  плз". Давайте конкретные вопросы, которые показывают что Вы пытались разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 64; i+=8) {
    string += '\n\t########';
}
```

Из разряда "каков вопрос"